# Load dynamic text to Tool tip in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mouseover

I have a for-each loop that iterates and lists the files in a table. I want to have a mouse hover that should query data from Database and display the details of corresponding file.
Following is the sample

```
@{ int count = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr style="height:40px;">

@{count++;
}

<td style="color:rgb(52, 116, 219);width:5%;">@count .</td>
<td> @Html.ActionLink(@item.Split('.')[0], "Usecase", new { name = item }, new { Class = "action add", title = <!-- I need to call my controller method from here and pass the @item parameter that will connect to DB and query selected file and load dynamic text-->  })</td>
</tr>
}
```

I dont know how to call controller method from the title attribute.Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why don't you just amend the model and add this tooltip text to it?

Answer (score 2):

@Maha.  As @Andrei suggested, add `Title` to your model and add the tooltip like I described in your last post.

As an example:

```
public class Car {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Make {get; set;}
    public string Color {get; set;}
    public string TitleTag {get; set;}  //use this to tie the Title text to the Model.
}
```

Then, like before:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Make, 
         "Action", 
         "Controller", 
         new { id = item.Id }, 
         new { @class = "css-class", @title = item.TitleTag }
```

Comment: Thanks! But where the model class is referenced in the view.FYI the item which I have mentioned refers to another model and the value to be displayed on tool tip has to refer another model class.How do I refer two model classes in the view

Comment: @Maha you need to create a view model